# Project Euler solution doesn't work: sum of all primes below two million

Tags: python

I am trying to do [Project Euler's problem 10](https://projecteuler.net/problem=10):

> The sum of the primes below 10 is 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17.
> Find the sum of all the primes below two million.

This is the code I wrote:

```
import math
def is_prime(number):
  if number <= 1:
    return False
  if number == 2:
    return True
  for i in range(3,int(math.sqrt(number))+1):
    if number % i ==0:
      return False
  else:
    return True 
all_primes = []
def check_prime():
  count = 1
  while count<2000000:
    if is_prime(count) == True:
      all_primes.append(count)
    count += 2
check_prime()
print(sum(all_primes))
```

It gives me an answer of 142913828920 which is wrong, very wrong. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you done any debugging? Which part is broken? Do you get the correct answer with `10`?

Comment: It's not 'very wrong' it's off by 2, if you look at your code it's very obvious why it is missing 2 from the list.  `check_prime` starts at 1 and goes up in increments of 2. Skipping the number 2.

Answer (score 0):

Logical flaws in the code. Few changes in lines 5, 7 and 18

```
  1 import math
  2 def is_prime(number):
  3   if number <= 1:
  4     return False
  5   if number in range(2,4):
  6     return True
  7   for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(number))+1):
  8     if number % i ==0:
  9       return False
 10   else:
 11     return True
 12 all_primes = []
 13 def check_prime():
 14   count = 1
 15   while count<10:
 16     if is_prime(count) == True:
 17       all_primes.append(count)
 18     count = count + 1
 19 check_prime()
 20 print(sum(all_primes))
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should change your approach to a simpler one using the sieve of Eratosthenes:

```
def primes(N):
    isPrime  = [True] * N
    if N>=3 : yield 2
    for p in range(3,N,2):
        if not isPrime[p]: continue
        isPrime[p*p::p] = [False] * len(isPrime[p*p::p])
        yield p

sum(primes(10)) # 17
```